# New anaconda release for M1 (2022.05)

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to install the new Anaconda for M1, I chose `64-Bit (M1) Graphical Installer (428 MB)`. However, when I download it, it still asks for Rosetta. Is that normal? I saw the demonstration here https://youtu.be/SPZRgwjclWQ and it doesn't ask for Rosetta.

Also, do you think keeping Miniforge is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Got your answer :) use the terminal installer, not GUI. I uninstalled first - I imagine that is required. Another difference is I installed in Users/myname/anaconda3/ rather than /opt/anaconda3/ which I was doing with GUI. Unknown if this makes a difference. I just tried to test it but I don't have perms to create the anaconda3 folder within opt, so I will leave it here.

Unknown whether kind being Apple Silicon means I can't use packages that lack an ARM version.

[image]

Comment: I think it s one of two things: 1) they have an option to have it based on M1 architecture, but only after you install using Rosetta like Adobe reader, or 2) it's a bug.

Comment: I see. Hope we can get this fixed. I've duplicated the question over at anaconda forums.

https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/anaconda-for-m1-is-kind-intel-despite-using-m1-installer/24059

Comment: @user18602524 edited, got an answer for you. hope it works.

Comment: I see, that s a point, I think all packages that will be able to be installed on Anaconda will somehow be configured to work with ARM.